Getting a 403 error when triggering a Cloud Function from a PubSub Topic
I created a cloud function that is triggered by a publish to a pubsub Topic. When I publish a message to the topic and read the funcition logs, I see this error:
"The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client"
If I understand the error correctly, it means that the entity calling the function does not have permission to do so. Who or that would be the caller in this case. The topic subscription?
My own function reads and writes to Cloud Storage and publishes to another topic, so I tried assigning a service-account to the function that has the roles pubsub.editor and storage.user, but it did not make a difference.
To bring it to basics, I tried following this tutorial step-by-step with the same result. The function in the tutorial just writes to the console.
This is the function code (from the tutorial)
use strict';

// [START functions_cloudevent_pubsub]
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

// Register a CloudEvent callback with the Functions Framework that will
// be executed when the Pub/Sub trigger topic receives a message.
functions.cloudEvent('helloPubSub', cloudEvent => {
  // The Pub/Sub message is passed as the CloudEvent's data payload.
  const base64name = cloudEvent.data.message.data;

  const name = base64name
    ? Buffer.from(base64name, 'base64').toString()
    : 'World';

  console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
});
// [END functions_cloudevent_pubsub]


Here is how I am creating the function:
gcloud pubsub topics create test-example-1
gcloud functions deploy nodejs-pubsub-function \
--gen2 \
--runtime=nodejs20 \
--region=europe-west1 \
--source=. \
--entry-point=helloPubSub \
--trigger-topic=test-example-1

Then, I trigger the function by publishing to the topic
gcloud pubsub topics publish test-example-1 --message="Friend"

And when I check the logs, I get this:
gcloud functions logs read   --gen2   --region=europe-west1   --limit=5   nodejs-pubsub-function
LEVEL    NAME                    TIME_UTC                 LOG
WARNING  nodejs-pubsub-function  2024-07-06 20:19:13.564  The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client
WARNING  nodejs-pubsub-function  2024-07-06 20:19:02.007  The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client
I        nodejs-pubsub-function  2024-07-06 20:17:16.448  Default STARTUP TCP probe succeeded after 1 attempt for container "worker" on port 8080.

I tried setting permissions to allUsers to invoke the function, but I don't have permissions on the project to do it:
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding nodejs-pubsub-function   --member=allUsers   --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker --region=europe-west1
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.add-iam-policy-binding) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy' denied on 'projects/***/locations/europe-west1/functions/nodejs-pubsub-function']

Could this lack of permission to set Iam policy be related? I don't get any errors when deploying the function with the above command


Could this lack of permission to set Iam policy be related? I don't get any errors when deploying the function with the above command

Yes. Either you need to add allUsers binding by having correct permissions to add them OR
add
--allow-unauthenticated flag when creating the CF.
